# How to use Session List<T> in asp.net to store value

Tags: c#, asp.net

i made one property like this :

```
public static List<Message> _SessionStore;
        public static List<Message> SessionStore
        {
            get
            {
                if(HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"]==null)
                {
                    _SessionStore = new List<Message>();
                }
                return _SessionStore;
            }
            set { HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"] = _SessionStore; }
        }
```

I want to add value `SessionStore.Add() and get SessionStore.Where()`
but i got error while doing this Add And Get

first i did **SessionStore.Add(comment);** somewhere then i got this error

```
 List<Message> msglist = HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"] as List<Message>;
    if(msglist.Count>0)
```

i am not able access `msglist`

can anybody fix my property in way that i can use this List from anypage to add and get values

Comment: You've shown the line the error happens on, you haven't shown us what the error itself is... Eg was it an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`? or what exactly did the exception say? Assuming I've got the right exception, it looks like you're not initialising your list

Comment: yes, it is :Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you forgot to put the `SessionStore` into the ASP.NET session, e.g:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"]==null)
{
    _SessionStore = new List<Message>();
    // the following line is missing
    HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"] = _SessionStore;
}
```

---

BTW: I think the `_SessionStore` field is not required. This should be enough:

```
public static List<Message> SessionStore
{
    get
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"]==null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"] = new List<Message>();
        }
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"] as List<Message>;
    }
}
```

And then, where you want to use the list of messages, you should access it via the `SessionStore` property, instead of via `HttpContext.Current.Session`:

```
List<Message> msglist = NameOfYourClass.SessionStore;
if(msglist.Count>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not store into session

```
get
{
    if(HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"]==null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"] = new List<Message>();
    }

    List<Message> list = HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"] as List<Message>;

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code

```
    public static List<Message> _SessionStore;
    public static List<Message> SessionStore
    {
        get
        {
            if(HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"]==null)
            {
                _SessionStore = new List<Message>();
            }
            return _SessionStore;
        }
        set 
        { 
            HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"] = value;
            _SessionStore = value;
        }
    }
```

This will store the value you set to SessionStore in the private version and the session